# How to determine size of website compared to others?

Tags: analytics

How does one determine the size of a website compared to others?

So if I know the approximate number of visitors per month and per day - is there some metric that can tell me the size of a website compared to others?

Answer (score 1):

There is no definitive way to get this information as no one has access to everyone's web stats. Heck, not every website even keeps stats. Even google analytics which is estimated to be used by half of the world's websites has this kind of information.

The best you can do use use tools like Alexa which guess based on users of their spyware and toolbar. But it is very inaccurate below the top 10,000 and really is useless information.

Answer (score 1):

As @JohnConde points out there is no real way to quantify the 'size' of a website, but you can [**benchmark**](http://analytics.blogspot.com/2008/03/benchmarking-now-available-plus.html) your website traffic against others in the same business category using Google analytics and other commercially available analytics products.

You do have to [allow google to anonymously share your analytics](http://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=webhp&source=hp&q=google%20analytics%20enable%20benchmarking&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&fp=8ed48c6cb037ec86&ix=sea&ion=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&biw=1600&bih=775) data with others in order to obtain this functionality though.

[Neilson](http://www.nielsen-online.com/resources.jsp?section=pr_netv) also offer website traffic rankings in the same way they offer audience size and demographic information for television programs in the US.

Comment: The Benchmarking feature is not available anymore in Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

[Google’s “site:” search operator allows you to see the URLs they have indexed for your website.](http://searchengineland.com/what-you-can-learn-from-googles-site-operator-14052)

> When you run a query using the “site:” operator...in the search results page (SERP) you’ll see something like: “Results 1 –
>   10 of about 162,000 from www.example.com.” Which means that they have
>   approximately 162,000 URLs of your website indexed.

Assuming the sites you wish to compare are well indexed by Google, you can use the site: search operator to get a **rough estimate** of the size of a website.